# Previous page's CSS loading?

Tags: css

This is a strange problem I  have never had before, and I can't find anything on it anywhere...

I have a home page with a "home.css" and another page (linked from the home page) with "page1.css" (so I'm using external style sheets).

If I type in page1 in my web address bar like "www.mysite.com/page1" then everything loads correctly. However, if I am at my home page and click the link to go to page 1, for some reason it is trying to use home.css instead of page1.css. However, if I hit the refresh button once page1 is loaded, it loads the correct style sheet.

I know its loading the home.css in page1 because a few of the divs share common names, and it is formatting those divs the way I defined them in home.css, so it is loading a css, just not the right one. The problem is coming in obviously with the uniquely named divs in page 1.

What am I missing?

Code in my **head** for home page:

```
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Code in my **head** for page1:

```
<link href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: some reason, the code didn't post.

Comment: Are you using any kind of templating? Server side or client side? Or using a single page app router like angular router?

Comment: Kevin, I am not using any templates.

Comment: Basic `<a href="">` for the navigation? No AJAX involved? The context markup would be useful.

Comment: gillesc ,

Basic a href, yes, no ajax. On a hunch, since typing in the address in the address bar worked, I changed the link from linking to the document within the site to a full http://www. address like I would for an outside site, and that worked. So, my links work now, but I don't think that should have been necessary.

Comment: Maybe a caching problem. Browsers are notorious for keeping the CSS for a page cached, long after the CSS files have changed.